# My cucumber tests are modifying the dev database. How do I get it to modify the test db instead?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

At the top of my features/support/env.rb file:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = 'test'
```

BUt the tests still modify the development db....
Even when I do

```
rake cucumber:authentication RAILS_ENV=test
```

it still changes the dev db

What else do I need to change?

database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: app_dev
  username: root
  password:

test:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: app_test
  username: root
  password:

production:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: app_production
  username: root
  password: 

cucumber: &CUCUMBER
    adapter: mysql
    encoding: utf8
    database: app_cuke
    username: root
    password:

culerity:
  <<: *CUCUMBER
```

using:

```
 ruby 1.8.7
    rails 2.3.8
    and cucumber 1.0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Also [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) might cause this because if there is a DATABASE_URL set in your .env file, this database will be used no matter what. This caused my tests to connect to my development database for me.

Answer (score 0):

check database.yml 
Probably you have specified development database for test env?

Well, basic install steps are

```
bundle install
rails generate cucumber:install
```

check database.yml, to specify right connection details

```
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

check cucumber

```
rake cucumber
```

what were the results of this steps?
especially have you created and migrated db for tests?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I solved it like this:

In `cucumber.rake` I added the rake task

```
task :ensure_test_env do
  ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test'
end
```

and then I made all cucumber tasks depend on it like

```
Cucumber::Rake::Task.new({:ok => ['db:test:prepare', :ensure_test_env]}, ...
```

Comment: This is a very old question and answer, but still a problem. Adding an explicit `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'test'` in cucumber.rake worked for me and ensured that cucumber used the test database instead of my development database. (I didn't add it as a separate task, though, but as an explicit setting.